# How to feed output of ShaderEffect back into the same ShaderEffect in QML/QtQuick2

Tags: fragment-shader, qtquick2

**Question**

I want to feed the output of a ShaderEffect into itself, effectively generating a feedback loop.

My naive attempts has included simply linking a ShaderEffectSource and a ShaderEffect like so:

```
    ShaderEffectSource {
        id:buf1;
        sourceItem:  effect;
    }

    ShaderEffect {
        id:effect;
        property variant src: buf1;
        //fragment shader then uses src as texture
    }
```

My next naive approach  included introducing a second ShaderEffectSource into the mix like so:

```
    ShaderEffectSource {
        id:buf1;
        sourceItem:  effect;
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id:buf2;
        sourceItem:  buf1;
    }

    ShaderEffect {
        id:effect;
        property variant src: buf2;
        //fragment shader then uses src as texture
    }
```

Neither of these approaches work however. It seems to work in one step but never feeds back in the end.

I have a feeling this is possible, but I am fairly new to QML and the quite possibly very logical and simple solution has eluded me. Any hints are welcome!

**Answer**

Answers with short working copy-pastable snippets are preferred :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved easily. From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-shadereffectsource.html#recursive-prop) I found that there is a `recursive property` that makes it possible with recursive shaders (duh)! So for example code:

```
ShaderEffectSource {
    id:buf1;
    recursive:true;
    sourceItem:  effect;
}

ShaderEffect {
    id:effect;
    property variant src: buf1;
    //fragment shader then uses src as texture
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some examples of using recursive ShaderEffectSource to do reaction-diffusion and fluid-dynamics effects on the UI linked from [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/44363/).

Comment: Actually I have been looking for that fluid dynamics code for a while now, but you kinda didn't answer the question so I kinda couldn't accept your answer. But thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: No problem, this was already ticked answered when I posted this; just thought it might give other folks stumbling on this question some inspiration what can be done with recursive shaders.